# how to merge compose file fragments correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I would like to merge the `seaweed-master-defaults` and `deploy_test01` fragments into the `seaweed_master_test01` service, see the example below:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

x-service-defaults: &service-defaults
    # common defaults for all services
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr

x-seaweeed-master-defaults: &seaweed-master-defaults
  image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
  volumes:
    - ${seaweed_dir}/master:/data
  <<: *service-defaults

x-seaweeed-volume-defaults: &seaweed-volume-defaults
  image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
  volumes:
    - ${seaweed_dir}/volume:/data
  <<: *service-defaults

x-deploy-test01: &deploy_test01
    # place instances on node01 only
    placement:
      constraints:
        - "node.labels.node==test01"

x-deploy-test02: &deploy_test02
    # place instances on node02 only
    placement:
      constraints:
        - "node.labels.node==test02"

x-deploy-test03: &deploy_test03
    # place instances on node03 only
    placement:
      constraints:
        - "node.labels.node==test03"
services:
  seaweed_master_test01:
    hostname: seaweed_master_test01
    command: 'master ${seaweed_master_opts} -mdir=/data -peers="seaweed_master_test02,seaweed_master_test03"'
    # service defaults PLUS place instances on node01 only
    <<: *seaweed-master-defaults
    deploy: *deploy_test01
  seaweed_master_test02:
    hostname: seaweed_master_test02
    command: 'master ${seaweed_master_opts} -mdir=/data -peers="seaweed_master_test01,seaweed_master_test03"'
    <<: *seaweed-master-defaults
    deploy: *deploy_test02
  seaweed_master_test03:
    hostname: seaweed_master_test03
    command: 'master ${seaweed_master_opts} -mdir=/data -peers="seaweed_master_test01,seaweed_master_test03"'
    <<: *seaweed-master-defaults
    deploy: *deploy_test03
  volume01:
    hostname: volume01
    command: 'volume -dataCenter=test01 -rack=rack1 ${seaweed_volume_opts} -dir=/data -mserver="seaweed_master_test01:9333,seaweed_master_test02:9333,seaweed_master_test03:9333"'
    <<: *seaweed-volume-defaults
    deploy: *deploy_test01
  volume02:
    hostname: volume02
    command: 'volume -dataCenter=test02 -rack=rack1 ${seaweed_volume_opts} -dir=/data -mserver="seaweed_master_test01:9333,seaweed_master_test02:9333,seaweed_master_test03:9333"'
    <<: *seaweed-volume-defaults
    deploy: *deploy_test02
  volume03:
    hostname: volume03
    command: 'volume -dataCenter=test03 -rack=rack1 ${seaweed_volume_opts} -dir=/data -mserver="seaweed_master_test01:9333,seaweed_master_test02:9333,seaweed_master_test03:9333"'
    <<: *seaweed-volume-defaults
    deploy: *deploy_test03
networks:
  default:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

My idea was to merge service defaults with instance placement, as follows:

```yaml
    # service defaults PLUS place instances on node01 only
    <<: *seaweed-master-defaults
    deploy: *deploy_test01
```

However, if I try `docker stack config --compose-file compose.yaml` then I see that the generated file looks like this:

```yaml
  seaweed_master_test01:
    command:
    - master
    - -defaultReplication=000
    - -volumeSizeLimitMB=1024
    - -mdir=/data
    - -peers=seaweed_master_test02,seaweed_master_test03
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.labels.node==test01
    hostname: seaweed_master_test01
    image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /srv/data/dev/seaweed/master
      target: /data
```

In other words, `*deploy_test01` overwrites everything under `deploy:`, instead of merging it.

How can I merge the two fragments so that the result is like this:

```yaml
    deploy:
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart_policy
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        #max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.labels.node==test01"
```

Comment: That is in fact the behavior specified by [Merge Key Language-Independent Type for YAML™ Version 1.1](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html): since `deploy:` is present in the parent mapping, it's ignored from the merge content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) pointed out in the comments: The YAML content gets merged at the top-level and will overwrite your settings.

To achieve your desired behavior, one could use a combination of [`extensions`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/11-extension/) and [`extends`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/). Unfortunately, `extends` is not available for `docker stack` (see this [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101)).

Another possible solution would be to use extensions on each separate level like:

```
version: "3.9"

x-restart-policy: &restart-policy
  condition: on-failure
  delay: 10s
  max_attempts: 3
  window: 120s

x-endpoint-mode: &endpoint-mode
  endpoint_mode: dnsrr

x-seaweeed-master-defaults: &seaweed-master-defaults
  image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
  volumes:
    - ${seaweed_dir}/master:/data

x-deploy-test01: &deploy_test01
    # place instances on node01 only
      constraints: [node.labels.node==test01]

services:
  seaweed_master_test01:
    hostname: seaweed_master_test01
    command: 'master ${seaweed_master_opts} -mdir=/data -peers="seaweed_master_test02,seaweed_master_test03"'
    # service defaults PLUS place instances on node01 only
    <<: *seaweed-master-defaults
    deploy:
      <<: *endpoint-mode
      restart_policy:
        <<: *restart-policy
      placement:
        <<: *deploy_test01
```

output:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  seaweed_master_test01:
    command:
    - master
    - -mdir=/data
    - -peers=seaweed_master_test02,seaweed_master_test03
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 2m0s
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.labels.node==test01
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    hostname: seaweed_master_test01
    image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /master
      target: /data
```

Comment: Yes, although this is very clumsy, I think that using `<<: *deploy_test01` instead of `constraints: [node.labels.node==test01]` has no real benefits, it just replaces a standard option with a fragment, without reducing the number of lines required. In fact, it increases complexity and reduces readability - the opposite of what should be done. But I guess, if this is the only way to do it, then I'll have to accept the answer.